# 90% of my users payments are going to Payment Pending Status in google play

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, trial

I am using the in-app-billing library from google for my in-app-subscriptions,most of my subscriptions after the trial ends remains in the payment pending status.what can I do?

I tried enabling pending purchase and also increased the grace period to 14 days but still no output